# How do I prove that the subset of unfixed transpositions from $A_4$ is normal to $A_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $K = \{\epsilon,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$

How can I show that $gK=Kg$ for all $g\in A_4$?

Without using the kernel is isomorphic to the the sign function, how would 
I prove that $K \trianglelefteq A_4?$

I understand that $K$ is the set of all transpositions in which no element is fixed. While playing around with the left and right cosets I observed that the composition of $g_1 \in A_4\setminus K$ with $K$ of the form $g_1K$ and $Kg_1$ resulted in the set $A_4\setminus K$. Similarly since $K\leq A_4$ and $K$ is abelian for any $g_1\in K$ then $g_1K=Kg_1=K$. It follows that $K\cup ( A_4 \setminus K) = A_4$ so for $g_1 \in A_4$ $g_1K=Kg_1=A_4$ so in fact $K\trianglelefteq A_4$.

Note:

$A_4\setminus K = \{(123),(132),(124),(142),(134),(143),(234),(243)\}$

I have observed as well that the composition of two 2-cycles with one 3-cycle and vise versa results in a 3-cycle.

Comment: Huh? Looks to me like no element of $K$ is a transposition, and one of the four elements of $K$ has several fixed points.

Comment: @bof $K$ is a set of disjoint cycles of transpositions. All of these disjoint cycles except for the identity element do not fix any elements.

Answer (score 2):

$gK=Kg$ is equivalent to $gKg^{-1}=K$. This means that $gag^{-1}\in K$
for all $a\in K$. But $gag^{-1}$ is a *conjugate* of $a$, and conjugates
have the same cycle structure. So $gag^{-1}$ is either the identity, or
has two cycles of length two. Either way, $gag^{-1}\in K$.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I am not that familiar with conjugacy classes, especially as they relate to cycles could you direct me to where I may do some further reading?I apologize if this question does not make much sense but, is this proof possible without using cyclic groups?

Comment: Thank you for the edit that makes a bit more sense. I am a bit confused how do we know that $gag^-1$ is a conjugate of a?

Comment: @user372382 That's pretty much the definition of conjugates. It is one of the basic results in permutation groups that conjugates have the same cycle structure. It's worthwhile finding this in a textbook, or better still, proving it for oneself.

Comment: But how do you know in this case that $gag^{-1}$ winds up being an element in $K$? Especially if $g \in A_4$ but not in $K$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want to describe $K$ by saying that $K\setminus\{e\}$ is the set of all involutions with no fixed point.  (Each of them happens to be a product of two commuting transpositions.  However, the transpositions themselves are not even in $A_4$.  A transposition is a permutation that moves exactly two points.)  The easiest way to see that $K$ is normal in $A_4$ is to see that it is a union of conjugacy classes.  But $e$ is its own conjugacy class, and all conjugates of permutations with a $2^22^2$ cycle structure have the same cycle structure, so that rest of $K$ is also a union of conjugacy classes (in fact $K\setminus\{e\}$ is a single conjugacy class as you can easily see but you don't need that).  But a subgroup is normal if and only if it is a union of conjugacy classes.  So $K$ is normal in $A_4$.  QED

Comment: Thank you, I apologize for using the incorrect terminology this is all very new to me. I'm not that familiar with conjugation classes or cyclic structure but I am beginning to see that this is the key to proving the normalcy of $K$ could you direct me towards resources which may allow me to expand my knowledge on the subject. Thank you for all of your help and for your detailed answer.

Comment: The best introduction to group theory is probably JJ Rotman's *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups*.  You can also find the material you need in Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*.  And there is always Marshall Hall's *The Theory of Groups* (which is inexpensive being in a Dover edition now...Hall's terminology is a little dated...he just calls a "conjugacy class" a "class").  None of these assume prior knowledge, and Rotman and Hall both cover conjugacy classes early on.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is tough to find good resources, I am doing this as an independent study currently using Dummit and Foote which has been a bit of a contrived read to say the least when it comes to these sections. I will explore the resources you mentioned. Thank you for your help.